# vim vnoremap: E488 Trailing characters

Tags: vim, shortcut

I'm using vim to program and I just want to make a shortcut for comment.

Here is how I set in `.vimrc`:

```
vnoremap <F7> :%s/^/\/\//g
```

I just want to add `//` in front of each selected line. However, when I press `<F7>` and press `Enter` in visual mode, I get an error:

```
E488 Trailing characters
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that when you press `F7` it just simulates pressing all the keys in the string. As soon as it presses `:` it gets into a state

```
:'<,'>
```

When it then types in all the rest of your command it gets into:

```
:'<,'>%s/^/\/\//g
```

Which is meaningless (`%` after `'<,'>` doesn't make sense). If you just remove `%` from your command, it will already work. Even better, add `<CR>` at the end so that you don't need to press Enter:

```
vnoremap <F7> :s/^/\/\//g<CR>
```

Comment: Thanks. Another question: why is the first column highlighted after typing `F7`? Can I avoid this?

Comment: @Thomas: it's not highlighted for me, so I guess it is some kind of other plugin you have, but try this: `vnoremap <F7> <C-v>I//<ESC>`

Comment: Or, rather, `vnoremap <F7> <C-v>^I//<ESC>`

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is very nice. I'm using this one now.

Comment: Btw, how do you set a shortcut to remove the comment?

Comment: I guess something like `vnoremap <F8> :s/^\/\///g` should work